# Why there is no overload of CreateDocumentQuery with RequestOptions

Tags: .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

As stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-consistency-levels)

> However, you can relax the consistency level of a specific read/query request by specifying the [x-ms-consistency-level] request header.

In DocumentDB .NET SDK (1.13.0) many methods (including READs and WRITEs) such as `ReadDatabaseAsync` have an overload with `RequestOptions` that allows you to choose the consistency.

The most used method `CreateDocumentQuery` does not have such an overload. Am I missing something (and it does not make sense to have `RequestOptions` for this method) or DocDb SDK developer forgot to add this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gap in the DocumentDB .NET SDK.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/243 is tracking support for `FeedOptions.ConsistencyLevel` to override the requested consistency level for queries and readfeeds.

Comment: This is actually implemented now, checked the latest library version 1.22.